# Livewire Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am using Livewire, and select2 to filter list of records in some table.
This is multicriteria search.The select dropdown is set with "multiple" option.
When I filter by chosing first item, the list is updated. when I choose another item, the list is updated but I am getting this:

```
LoadingStates.js:192 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
at LoadingStates.js:192
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at startLoading (LoadingStates.js:190)
at setLoading (LoadingStates.js:161)
at LoadingStates.js:50
at MessageBus.js:17
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at MessageBus.value (MessageBus.js:16)
at Object.call (HookManager.js:38)
at Object.callHook (Store.js:120)
```

And i cannot choose another item, it seems this creates infinite loop because I get it more and more and I am not able anymore to do anything.

The select is blade component. here is its html:

```
<div>
@props(['datas', 'label'])
<div wire:ignore>
    <select class="form-control select2" {{ $attributes }}>
        @foreach($datas as $key => $item)
            <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->$label }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

In my livewire component I use it like:

```
<div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="myField1" class="font-weight-bold">Field 1 list</label>
       <x-utils.select2 class="form-control multiselect" name="myField1" multiple
                            wire:model="myField1" :datas="$field1datas" label="name"/>
     </div>
</div>
...

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
                        @if ($queryResults->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($queryResults as $key => $a)
                            <tr wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}">
                                <td>$a->content</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

And my livewire component script is :

```
 function initSelect2() {
    $('.select2').select2({
        allowClear: true,
        placeholder: 'Veuillez faire un choix',
        language: "fr",
        width: "100%",
    }).on('change', function(e){
        console.log($(this).select2("val"));
        @this.set($( this).attr('name'), ( $(this).select2("val") ? $(this).select2("val") : $(this).val() ) );
    });
 }
 initSelect2();
 document.addEventListener("livewire:load", () => {
    Livewire.hook('message.processed', () => {
        initSelect2();
    });
});
```

It seems the error

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null

is about query datas retuned as the filter result but I don't know why.
I check this here: https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/2537 but this doesn't help me.
How to fix this?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to close the div tag.

```
<div>
    @props(['datas', 'label'])
    <div wire:ignore>
        <select class="form-control select2" {{ $attributes }}>
            @foreach($datas as $key => $item)
                <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $item->$label }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your livewire component, you made a mistake.

From documentation: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/troubleshooting#root-element-cures

The solution is to ensure that you only have one root HTML element, such as a . If you have multiple elements, then wrap everything in a  or another element that suits your layout.

```
<div>
  <div>
     <div class="form-group">
       <label for="myField1" class="font-weight-bold">Field 1 list</label>
       <x-utils.select2 class="form-control multiselect" name="myField1" multiple
                            wire:model="myField1" :datas="$field1datas" label="name"/>
     </div>
</div>
...

<table class="table">
    <tbody>
                        @if ($queryResults->count() > 0)
                        @foreach($queryResults as $key => $a)
                            <tr wire:key="{{ $loop->index }}">
                                <td>$a->content</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                        @endif
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```